# Andoid App install workaround, country device not valid

Tags: google-play-store, apk, google-apps

I have a Galaxy Note Pro 12.2 (P905 with Sim) and the device itself is great, but I do regularly encounter "This app is incompatible with your device." and "This item cannot be installed in your device's country".

I've played around, rooted, revised and corrupted build.prop, reinstalled (cost be £40) all in an attempt to workaround, all to no avail thus far.

Further research has also indicated the issue could be to do with Sim, Camera and other "add-ons" which could give rise to the above restrictions re installation.

My latest endeavour gives rise to this question.

Are these contraints purely related to Google Play Store?
If this is the case, could I not obtain, via download the APK file (my test is for Churchill Solitaire), and install direct without going via Play Store.  Would this circumvent the above issues?
I guess the only real test is to try but before I did I thought I'd ask.

Cheers
PG

Comment: Just sideload the APKs, under most circumstances the restrictions are just forced on you. Whether the app works *nicely* on the tablet itself is another question (esp. stretching caused by screen).

Answer (score 0):

Developers may restrict their apps to work only on certain devices, countries, and some versions of Android. But, you can bypass theoe restrictions to install apps that are “not compatible with your device.”

**P.S:** You should have **ROOT** access to fool Play Store, but didn't guarantee if the apks will work correctly on your device.

I won't tell you why some apps are not compatible with your device? and on your Android device, Those won’t appear in Play Store search results. You are seeing those incompatible apps on the Google Play website only.

**How to bypass device restrictions ?**

On your system partition there is a **build.prop** file storing the device,  brand and manufacturer.

if you have **ROOT** access device, you can edit the **build.prop** manually and change your device model and brand entirely. This will allow you to install apps that are marked as compatible with your new spoofed device., the values to be modified are:

```
ro.product.model
ro.product.brand
ro.product.name
ro.product.device
ro.product.manufacturer
ro.build.fingerprint
```

Be careful, when dealing with `ro.build.Fingerprint`

You can simply download [Device Spoofer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scheffsblend.devicespoof&hl=en) apk from Play Store on your device. Once it’s installed, don't forget **ROOT** is required; launch the apk and spoof your device to any model available on the list. after rebooting your device, You can then install apps compatible with that new device.

Tricks for Installing Country-Restricted Apps
Some apps are only available in certain countries. If you have forgotten to install your bank’s app before travelling or you want to install a video or music-playing app that’s not available in your country, you may be able to fool Google into thinking your device is actually in another country.

We have used these tricks in the past to install US-only apps from outside the US. However, none of these tricks worked for us when we tried them while composing the article. It’s possible that Google is sure our account is outside the US because we have paid with a non-US payment method on Google Play. However, we have included these tips in the hopes that they may still work for some of you.

**How to install country restricted apk?**

Just use any VPN apk from Play Store to Install country restricted apks. Use Wi-Fi only when using Play Store, and disable cellular connection with AirPlane Mode.

VPN applications **don’t need ROOT** access. just restart your device, connect to another country's VPN, and then open the Google Play app. Your device should be located in another country. maybe you need to clear Google Play Store data & cache to detect device’s new country.
Install the App’s APK File
If an app is marked as incompatible because you’re in the wrong country, you may be able to locate the app’s .APK file and sideload it onto your device.

**Install apk from unknown sources**

- On your device, downlaod the APK file you want from sources other than Play Store.
- Launch any File Explorer apk and navigate to your downloaded apk (Tick the option "Install from Unknown Sources" on your device Settings)

**P.S:** Downloading and installing apks from web include many security risks. You shouldn’t download APKs from untrusted sources.